# i fixed 'SettingWithCopyWarning', but i don't know how i did it

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    'A' : ['one.', 'two.', 'three.', 'four.', 'five.'],
    'B' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

and df was like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeRkX.png)

and i wanted to put 'step' in the end of every single 'A' column elements.

```
for i in range(0,5,1):
    if str(df['A'][i]).endswith('.'):
        df['A'][i] = df['A'][i] + 'step' 
df
```

and it [worked,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHG41.png)
but there was a warning:

```
[file path]: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['A'][i] = df['A'][i] + 'step'
```

so i approached little bit differently,

```
for i in range(0,5,1):
    if str(df.loc[i,'A']).endswith('.'):
        df.loc[i, 'A'] = df.loc[i, 'A'] + 'step' 
df
```

and this worked without `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

my question is, what's the difference between `df['A'][i]` and `df.loc[i, 'A']`?
and why `df.loc[i, 'A']` didn't make any warning?

Comment: It's explained in [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing). Also, the "pandas" way in your case would be `df['A'] = np.where(df['A'].str.endswith('.'), df['A'] + 'step', df['A'])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang i read the docs, and i totally understand it. thank you! it was really helpful! plus i appreciate letting me know 'pandas' way!